# How to translate Overview and Outline?

Tags: sintaxis, ciencia

I am writing a thesis and would like to add 2 subsections in my Introduction 
Overview, and Outline, what would be the best way to translate them to spanish?

Estoy realizando una tesis, pero quiero agregar 2 sub-secciones  Overview, y un Outline en la Introducción, ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de ponerlas en español?

Comment: ¿De que es la Tesis? Por ejemplo en Medicina se utiliza vocabulario específico. (Material y Método) y en otras materias de la ciencia puede que también. Aquí me parece que lo más exacto pudieran ser Síntesis y Vision General. Pero es recomendable saber la materia de la tesis.

Comment: Ok, me parece muy buena tu respuesta :D

Comment: Pero te repito, según las especialidades por ejemplo para outline puede usarse Síntesis , pero tambien, Reseña, y también Resumen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parecen apropiados: **Síntesis** y **Visión General**