# Does the word "overview" just not translate easily into Spanish and how is it translated outside of an academic paper?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

When answering a question, context is everything, and though I was excited when I saw that someone had already asked

[**How to translate Overview and Outline?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/how-to-translate-overview-and-outline)

as well as

[**What is a good translation for the “overview” other than “síntesis”?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/what-is-a-good-translation-for-the-overview-other-than-s%c3%adntesis)

the questions seemed geared toward an academic paper and I just wasn't really satisfied with the answers that were given.  Let me give you some background so you can understand why.

I've been spending some time translating the occasional Wikipedia page I find if it is a topic of interest and I happen to notice it has not been translated into Spanish.  Recently, I came upon an article with a section titled "Overview."  It is not unusual to find a section titled as such on English Wikipedia pages.

While attempting to translate this word, I discovered that "overview" can be translated with a number of different words, but I narrowed my selection down to the following:

**visión general**

**resumen**

**sinopsis**

**reseña**

and ultimately selected "reseña," but I didn't feel really confident about that choice.  So, I decided to find English Wikipedia articles with the word "overview" that had been translated into Spanish.  I searched through at least 10 articles randomly selected from among 100 that met that criteria, but none had a direct translation for "overview."  Some dissected the section by naming a section with "Historia" or by adding a section for the definition of the subject topic, but I have yet to find one that translates "overview" with any of the typical and numerous translations I see listed for it.  For a Wikipedia article, which of the four words I listed above is the best translation for "overview" or is there a better word altogether?

Comment: In [What is a good translation for the “overview” other than “síntesis”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5612/1674)  there is an accepted answer with plenty of suggestions and it does not seem to be geared towards an academic paper. I think for the context of Wikipedia, both _resumen_ and (maybe even better) _introducción_ seem to be a good match.

Comment: So I am closing the question as duplicate. If you feel that it still does not match your needs, then please [edit] your question with specific details so we can reopen it. Thanks!

Comment: Considering this is for a Wikipedia page, here is my take. *Resumen* seems to indicate the following section is an abstract of the whole article, not an historical overview. *Introducción* would a better option, but still overviews aren't always necessarily introductory. *Panorama* is generally used to define the cultural, political, etc situation in which something happens (a book is written, a king is crowned, etc). *Sinopsis* could work, but honestly I've only encountered it when reading books/movies reviews. (+)

Comment: (+) *Reseña* has overtones of critique (*reseñas* are generally a *sinopsis* plus the writer's personal opinion). *Compendio* and *plan de charla* don't work for obvious reasons. Depending on the content of the article, *historia* or *introducción histórica* could be appropriate, but I think *visión general*, although vaguer than *overview*, works the best.

Comment: @fedorqui  I will admit that I didn't closely read (i.e., read word for word) the answer at the thread you reference, but what I really appreciate is your comment, especially this line here, _"I think for the context of Wikipedia, both resumen and (maybe even better) introducción seem to be a good match."_  In addition to that, thank you for being so courteous about it all.  Your interest in truly helping me displays a high level of professionalism and it is appreciated.

Comment: Appreciate your comments, @Yay.  I had a feeling _reseña_ wasn't the best choice, but since the others were cognates of English and ones that didn't quite fit my concept of what an overview is, I went with a word I was least familiar with -- _reseña_.  I also appreciate your comments about _historia_ being a potential good choice for translation.  I see that word a fair amount in Spanish Wikipedia articles, so it meshes well with my observations.  Again, thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: @LisaBeck It is always a pleasure to interact with you : ) Thanks for making things easy!